# Extracting boundary of a numpy array

Tags: numpy, mask

Let `A` be a numpy array representing a mask. I would like to extract the boundary corresponding to this mask i.e, make everything zero except for the boundary.

eg:

```
In [22]: A
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

The required output is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Further, the mask in `A` could be non-linear as well.

So, my question is, what's the most efficient way get this boundary?

Edit 1:
What I mean by non-linear?
Consider an image in which there is a person. The mask corresponding to this person is non-linear.

Comment: Is the mask area known to be rectangular and to be aligned only either horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Nope. The mask could be non-linear as well. I've updated the question on what I mean by non-linear boundary

Comment: So when you say "non-linear" you mean the edges aren't straight lines oriented horizontally or vertically?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One trick to get the contour would be to use binary dilation with 3x3 ones array as the kernel on the negated mask and look for the common ones between it and input. For `4-connected` boundary, it would be all ones array and for `8-connected` a plus-shaped ones array -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

k = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int) # for 4-connected
k = np.zeros((3,3),dtype=int); k[1] = 1; k[:,1] = 1 # for 8-connected
out = binary_dilation(a==0, k) & a
```

Sample run -

Input array :

```
In [384]: a
Out[384]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [385]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation
```

Solve for 4-connected :

```
In [386]: k = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int)

In [390]: binary_dilation(a==0, k) & a
Out[390]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Solve for 8-connected :

```
In [411]: k = np.zeros((3,3),dtype=int); k[1] = 1; k[:,1] = 1

In [412]: k
Out[412]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])

In [413]: binary_dilation(a==0, k) & a
Out[413]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

We could also use `binary_erosion` :

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion
out = a-binary_erosion(a,k)
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I've been looking for.