# Most computationally efficient way to batch alter values in each array of a 2d array, based on conditions for particular values by indices

Tags: arrays, numpy

Say that I have a batch of arrays, and I would like to alter them based on conditions of particular values located by indices.

For example, say that I would like to increase and decrease particular values if the difference between those values are less than two.

For a single 1D array it can be done like this

```
import numpy as np

single2 = np.array([8, 8, 9, 10])

if abs(single2[1]-single2[2])<2:
    single2[1] = single2[1] - 1
    single2[2] = single2[2] + 1
single2
```

```
array([ 8,  7, 10, 10])
```

But I do not know how to do it for batch of arrays. This is my initial attempt

```
import numpy as np

single1 = np.array([6, 0, 3, 7])
single2 = np.array([8, 8, 9, 10])
single3 = np.array([2, 15, 15, 20])

batch = np.array([
    np.copy(single1),
    np.copy(single2),
    np.copy(single3),
])

if abs(batch[:,1]-batch[:,2])<2:
    batch[:,1] = batch[:,1] - 1
    batch[:,2] = batch[:,2] + 1
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Looking at np.any and np.all, they are used to create an array of booleans values, and I am not sure how they could be used in the code snippet above.

My second attempt uses np.where, using the method described here for comparing particular values of a batch of arrays by creating new versions of the arrays with values added to the front/back of the arrays.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297663/3259896

In the case of the example, I am comparing values that are right next to each other, so I created copies that shift the arrays forwards and backwards by 1. I also use only the particular slice of the array that I am comparing, since the other numbers would also be used in the comparison in np.where.

```
batch_ap = np.concatenate(
    (batch[:, 1:2+1], np.repeat(-999, 3).reshape(3,1)), 
    axis=1
)

batch_pr = np.concatenate(
    (np.repeat(-999, 3).reshape(3,1), batch[:, 1:2+1]), 
    axis=1
)
```

Finally, I do the comparisons, and adjust the values

```
batch[:, 1:2+1] = np.where(
    abs(batch_ap[:,1:]-batch_ap[:,:-1])<2,
    batch[:, 1:2+1]-1,
    batch[:, 1:2+1]
)

batch[:, 1:2+1] = np.where(
    abs(batch_pr[:,1:]-batch_pr[:,:-1])<2,
    batch[:, 1:2+1]+1,
    batch[:, 1:2+1]
)
print(batch)
```

```
[[ 6  0  3  7]
 [ 8  7 10 10]
 [ 2 14 16 20]]
```

Though I am not sure if this is the most computationally efficient nor programmatically elegant method for this task. Seems like a lot of operations and code for the task, but I do not have a strong enough mastery of numpy to be certain about this.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
mask = abs(batch[:,1]-batch[:,2])<2
batch[mask,1] -= 1
batch[mask,2] += 1
```